# How to change the font of Bootstrap tooltips

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Using the Tooltip plugin that is incorporated in bootstrap.js, how can I change the font that the text inside the tooltip is written in? No matter how hard I tried, the only success I've had was changing the text defined in my * selector. My bootstrap is activated with jQuery using this: `$(".myTooltip").tooltip({html: "true", placement: "auto-right", delay: {"show": 300, "hide": 100}});`
The tooltip is being shown next to this image:
 `<img title="<ul class='text-left'><li>Some text</li><li><em>More Text</em></li><li>Cost</li></ul>" class="myTooltip" src="image.png" />`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bootstrap decorates tooltips via two classes - `.tooltip` of `.tooltip-inner`. Here's a fragment from `bootstrap.css`:

```js
.tooltip {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: normal;
  /* ... */
}
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

So you can setup tooltips by yourself:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".my-tooltip").tooltip({
    html: "true", 
    placement: "auto-right", 
    delay: {"show": 300, "hide": 100}
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.tooltip {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #ffc;
  color: #c00;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<img title="<ul class='text-left'><li>Some text</li><li><em>More Text</em></li><li>Cost</li></ul>" class="my-tooltip" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssdlq.jpg" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```